# How to set up with Hibernate Criterion for 2 conditions ((x and Y) or (a and b))

Tags: java, hibernate

The SQL I want to create using Hibernate is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE ...(another condition I have already handled here)
    AND ((billingCompleted = 0 AND terminationDate IS NULL)
      OR (billingCompleted = 0 AND terminationDate IS NOT NULL))
```

What I tried with no success so far is this:

```
itemCriteria.add(Restrictions.and(
    Restrictions.or(
        (Restrictions.eq("billingCompleted", new Integer(0)), 
         Restrictions.isNotNull("terminationDate")),    
        (Restrictions.eq("billingCompleted", new Integer(0)), 
         Restrictions.isNull("terminationDate"))))));
```

How do I need to format this in order to set this up right for Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing strictly as you want, the restriction is going to be:

```
Restrictions.and(
        Restrictions.or(
                Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("billingCompleted", 0),  Restrictions.isNotNull("terminationDate")),
                Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("billingCompleted", 0), Restrictions.isNull("terminationDate"))));
```

But, your expression can be simplified to

```
Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("billingCompleted", 0));
```

because you want `billingCompleted = 0` and `terminationDate is null or terminationDate is not null`. The last always evaluates to `true`, `X and true === X`, so we can simply remove that condition.